# How to retain the URL of lowest price variant in Page source

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I have a requirement where I need to retain the url of the lowest price variant in the canonical tags in PDP.
Currently, I am trying to fetching all variants of the product in PDP and getting the price of each one, compare their price and return the URL of the lowest price variant.
But price attributes are not getting populated in ProductData.Here prodModel is the ProductModel.

final ProductData productData = productConverter.convert(prodModel);

Comment: I am trying to populate the ProductData using target.setPrice(priceRow.getPrice()); But getting errors

Answer (score 0):

Where you are trying to write your logic?

Can you attach what error you are getting for more clarification?